# Change database in Resource model

Tags: magento2, database, resource-model, table, database-connection

I split my database on 3 parts.
In my env php is set default, but in one of my model i need to connect to table wich located in different db.
How can i change target db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this docs is what you need.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master_masterdb.html

of course you have to make an adjustment to your needs

Cheers